# issue with pagination being picked up by conditional

Tags: pagination

I have some code that creates my breadcrumbs and it uses this conditional:

```
{if segment_1 == "media" && segment_2 != "media-view" && segment_2 != ""}
<li class="breadcrumb"><p><a href="{site_url}index.php/media">Media</a></p></li>
<li class="breadcrumb"><p>{title}</p></li>
{/if}
```

The problem is that now there are enough media files to have multiple pages, and the pagination becomes segment_2, so it's no longer blank.  So now the page is broken because its trying to put in a bunch of junk for the breadcrumbs.

How do you match against pagination?  Is there a wildcard character so I could say something like the following?

```
{if segment_2 == "P%"}
```

It's been a while since I used EE and I can't seem to find the answer.  thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use MoVariables : http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables

You can check a conditional against pagination.

There is probably a better way to do this, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The default EECMS conditionals can't check against RegEx, so your simplest solution is to use [Switchee](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee/).

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}/{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="#^media/P\d+$#|media/media-view|media/"}
        {!-- for this case, we show nothing --}
    {/case}

    {case value="media/{segment_2}"}
        <li class="breadcrumb"><p><a href="{site_url}index.php/media">Media</a></p></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb"><p>{title}</p></li>
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

To avoid complex and hard to debug RegEx, I created one first case to exclude all three situations you need to, separated by `|`:

- `segment_1 == media` and `segment_2` as pagination: `^media/P\d+$`, where`#` delimits a RegEx;
- `segment_1 == media` and `segment_2 == 'media-view'`: `media/media-view`;
- `segment_1 == media` and `segment_2` empty: `media/`.

If the first case doesn't match, then the second will be tested.